# Show Footer when user stops scrolling the page in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, footer

How can i make a footer visible when user stops scrolling the page. Currently the footer is visible only when user scrolls till bottom. But i want to show the footer any time the user stops scrolling down in between.

See https://prnt.sc/pm8jjv

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer-bottom{
position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1D2C6F;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**I hope this will help you!!!**

Comment: No this does not help. i want to show and hide the footer based on scroll. i dont want to make it sticky